# Laravel - How to use string type of created_at in only method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to load specific attributes with user model  :

```
$user = $user->only(['id', 'user_name', 'created']);
```

but created_at gets an object of date_time something like this:

```
 {
 "id": 1,
 "user_name": "foo",
 "created_at": {
    "date": "2018-12-30 11:34:57.000000",
    "timezone_type": 3,
    "timezone": "...."
 },
}
```

how can i get string type of created_at with only method?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

Either you could set a `$casts[]` array on your model as such:

```
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'string'
];
```

which means, everytime you will try to access `created_at`, it will return a string representation.

Or, you could also define an [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) such as

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute()
{
    return (string) $this->created_at; 
}
```

However, I don't usually like to mess with the `created_at` and `updated_at` attributes. So usually I'd do something like this:

```
public function getFormattedCreatedAtAttribute()
{
    return $this->created_at->toFormattedDateString();
}
```

and then in your particular case, it would be:

```
$user = $user->only(['id', 'user_name', 'formatted_created_at']);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
'create_at' => now();
```

or
'crated_at' => Carbon::now();
'updated_at' => Carbon::now();